# Loops through Access Table and for each Column with Data

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba

I think this should be simple, but I can't find the right way to do it. I have a table with an ID number column, and 10 rows following it labeled Question #1, Question #2, and so forth.

There are no duplicate ID numbers, but each ID number could have more than one row of questions.

I would like to take the ID row and for each different question where applicable create a new row with the same ID.  So if an ID number has a question listed under the Question #1 and Question #2, Id like to create a duplicate for that ID number and have have both questions listed under one column Lets call it "Total Questions", and grouped by that ID number.  This can be done by creating a new table.

Example:

**From:**

```
+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|  ID   |        Question #1        |        Question #2        |
+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 11111 | Was it notated correctly? | Was it completed on time? |
+-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

**To:**

```
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|  ID   | Total Questions                     |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
| 11111 | Was it notated correctly?           |
| 11111 | Was it completed on time?           |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is confusing. You say Access table in the title, but then only have tagged 'excel', 'loops', and 'excel-vba'. So are these tables in Access or not? If so, you could perform a query (no loops needed) on the original table to output the way you want.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing a reference to excel anywhere.  I am referring to an Access table though.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using `DAO`

```vb
sub SomeProcedure()
    Dim db as DAO.Database, recIn as DAO.Recordset, recOut as DAO.Recordset

    Set db = currentdb()
    Set recIn = db.openRecordset("yourQuestionsInputTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
    Set recOut = db.openRecordset("yourQuestionsOutputTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)

    with recIn
        .moveFirst
        do
            for i = 1 to .Fields.count
                if left(.Fields(i).Name, 8) = "Question" then
                    recOut.addNew
                        recOut.Fields("Id") = .fields("Id")
                        recOut.Fields("Total Questions") = .Fields(i)
                    recOut.update
                end if
            next i
            .moveNext
        loop until .EOF
    end with
    recIn.close
    recOut.close
    db.close
end sub
```

---

**The explanation:**

What I'm doing is:

1. Read each record from the input table
2. For each column wich name begins with `"Question"`, create a new record in the output table, with the `Id` of the input table, and the value of the selected column.

---

This is just a draft. You'll need to tweak the code to fit your needs.

Hope this helps.

---

**Alternatives**

After thinking a little, I may have an alternative to the problem you mention in your comments.

I think you can change the loop like this:

```
' You'll need a variable of type Field
Dim f as DAO.Field ' Check if this is right
' Some code
with recIn
    .moveFirst
    do
        for f in .Fields
            if left(f.Name, 8) = "Question" then
                recOut.addNew
                    recOut.Fields("Id") = .Fields("Id").Value
                    recOut.Fields("Total Questions") = .Fields(f.Name).Value
                recOut.update
            end if
        next f
        .moveNext
    loop until .EOF
end with
' More code
```

Instead of iterating on the `Fields` collection with an index, this will iterate with any `Field` member in it. That should avoid the "Item not found in collection" issue.

***Warning:*** Not tested

Comment: Thanks Barranka! this seems to explain what I'm trying to accomplish, I've adjusted the code but I'm now having problems getting it to loop to the next ID number. It runs the first ID number perfectly for all questions but after that I get an "Item Not Found in Collection" error.  I've tried a few different things based on my knowledge of VBA to no avail. Any recommendations?

Comment: @user3738222 Sorry! I forgot to add the `.next` line in the code (to jump to the next record in `recIn`). As for the "Item not found in collection", you should debug your code and see where it is happening (execute it step by step and check where the execution raises an error). If the table behind `recIn` has a fixed number of columns, modify the loop to consider only the columns that you need.

Comment: I receive the "Item not found in this collection" error whenever it reaches the last Question (Question #10) column. The code is actually adding the ID number 10 times (1 time per each question) I'm ok with that, but once it loops through the columns for the first ID number it fails to go to the next ID number and do the same. adding .Next gave it a "method or data member not found" error so I did .MoveNext and received the same item error.

Comment: @user3738222 Sorry (I've not programmed in VBA in quite a while); the correct method is `.moveNext`. As for the "Item not found in collection", it may be an issue with the index of the field (the value of `i`). I don't quite remember if the index starts in zero or one. Use `debug.print recIn.fields(i).Name` to show in the inmediate window which field is being read. By the way... you understand what this thing is doing, right? (check [The Ten Commandments of Access](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm) ;) )

Comment: lol yes I understand what it is doing. I have a similar code I use for something else. I just think the code you provided looked perfect to me, not sure why it fails once it loops back to the If line once the column end. I appreciate your help! you definitely put me in the right direction. I'll keep trying different things to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try a couple queries like this:

```
SELECT ID, Question1 AS TotalQuestions
INTO NewTable
FROM OriginalTable;

SELECT ID, Question2 AS TotalQuestions
INTO NewTable
FROM OriginalTable;
```