# VBA or SQL to Subgroup data under two columns?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

An MS Access query gives me the below output:

[image: Query output]

I am trying to sort the above data in VBA and transfer into an Excel sheet pre-formatted as below:

[image: Output into Formatted Excel sheet]

I am trying to use the instruction in the post, [Sql group rows with same value, and put that value into header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956065/sql-group-rows-with-same-value-and-put-that-value-into-header?rq=1), but my query gives a huge output ~30000 rows over a date range which requires a different approach to sort.

I am trying to use the below logic

1. Extract unique serial entries from the query first
2. Extract all unique users for that serial
3. Use both serial and user combination further in a 2 level nested loop to extract the 'value' and 'result' from the same query into a separate table and keep appending to it until I have looped through all serials

I am unable to get the right code for this. Please help. What I have tried:

First query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(serial) AS Serial Number FROM Test_Results_Tbl;
```

Second Query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(user) AS Username FROM Test_Results_Tbl where serial = var_serial;
```

Should I follow below approaches?

- [Loops through Access Table and for each Column with Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373454/loops-through-access-table-and-for-each-column-with-data)
- [Export Query in VBA loop to select data based on String Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725653/export-query-in-vba-loop-to-select-data-based-on-string-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do several left joins from the table Test_Results_Tbl to itself and look for each of the test results with distinct records.

I quickly replicated your input table and here is the sql for the query I created.

```
SELECT DISTINCT test.SerialNo, test.User, test.StartDate, test_1.TestValue, test_1.Result, test_2.TestValue, test_2.Result, test_3.TestValue, test_3.Result
FROM ((test LEFT JOIN test AS test_1 ON (test.StartDate = test_1.StartDate) AND (test.User = test_1.User) AND (test.SerialNo = test_1.SerialNo)) LEFT JOIN test AS test_2 ON (test.StartDate = test_2.StartDate) AND (test.User = test_2.User) AND (test.SerialNo = test_2.SerialNo)) LEFT JOIN test AS test_3 ON (test.StartDate = test_3.StartDate) AND (test.User = test_3.User) AND (test.SerialNo = test_3.SerialNo)
WHERE (((test_1.Testname)="test1") AND ((test_2.Testname)="test2") AND ((test_3.Testname)="test3"));
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWUO1.jpg) is a picture from the query design view.

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzM1f.jpg) is a picture of the query results.

Comment: Thanks! great method...works perfectly :-)... I need to do the same for 46 tests set table...Will access allow 47 joins from a table to itself?

Comment: According to [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854) looks like the max is 32 tables in a query. Another option would be to: create a table that has a field for SerialNo, User, StartDate, and two fields for each test (Value, Result). Insert records using an append query for the first 15-20 tests and then use an update query to update the remaining tests.